# Operation failed with status 2: No such file or directory. How to recover?

Tags: macos, encryption, time-machine, macos-sonoma

I have an external backup disk for my Macbook. The disk has two partitions and both are encrypted. One partition has a copy of the systemdisk of my Macbook, the second keeps a Time Machine backup.

- First partition:

  - copy of macOS systemdisk
  - decrypts and mounts
- Second partition:

  - Time Machine backup
  - decrypt popup appears
  - after entering password nothing happens, doesn't show in Finder
  - after entering password, Disk Utitily won't start anymore

I can mount the first partition, and if I cancel the second:

- When I open DU, I see: CoreStorage Logical Volume.
- Clicking Mount: popup says "Invalid disk"
- Running First Aid: First Aid process has failed.

Below you see the output from the diskutil cli command and an attempt at creating an image from the partition using DU.

**% diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         150.1 GB   disk4s2
   3:          Apple_CoreStorage TIME5                   3.9 TB     disk4s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk4s4

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +150.1 GB   disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume SYSTEM1 - data          78.7 GB    disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 84.7 MB    disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                533.8 MB   disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk5s4
   5:                APFS Volume SYSTEM1                 11.1 GB    disk5s5

Offline
                                 Logical Volume TIMEMACHINE1 on disk4s3
                                 867ABC77-8899-4CF4-8627-D12345
                                 Locked Encrypted
```

**Creating disk image from “TIMEMACHINE1”**

```
Operation failed with status 2: No such file or directory
```

**DD**

I copied the partition over to another disk using dd. Mounting resulted in another error:

```
hdiutil attach -readonly  /Volumes/externaldisk/TIMEMACHINE1.img
hdiutil: attach failed - image not recognised
```

---

**Questions**

Is this a lost cause? What can I try to fix this disk or disk image?

Comment: All you can really do with APFS is run First Aid [yup, really. Don't you miss the greats like DiskWarrior?]. Start from the bottom of the list in the GUI DU & work your way upwards through every volume, container, disk. People have mentioned going through this twice may help, but I fear that may just be wishful thinking.